# Typescript 3.0 with $(document).ready

Tags: typescript3.0

The generally described method for subscribing to jQuery document.ready() in Typescript seems to be the following

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        jQuery(document).ready(() => {
           ...
        });
    }
}
```

However in Typescript 3.0 I'm getting an error..

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call type...
should have type assignment to string...
but has type 'Document'
```

Is this a bug or what is the correct signature.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem with Typescript 3.1, jQuery 3.3.1 and DefinitelyTyped definitons for jQuery 3.3.29. Have you perhaps fixed your problem? This question seems to be dead.

Comment: No, though I did get some comments elsewhere that invoking document.ready() in the constructor was bad practice, but no actionable input

Comment: I went on to ask this question on my own and did receive a satisfactory answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432202/cannot-use-document-ready-in-typescript

Comment: Basically, `$(() => {...})` is equivalent and `ready` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer taken from [Cannot use `$(document).ready` in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432202/cannot-use-document-ready-in-typescript)

$(document).ready(handler) has two functionally equivalent variants, first is $().ready(handler), and second is direct $(handler).

In jQuery 3.0 first two were deprecated, leaving only $(handler). The official justification is:

> This is because selection has no bearing on the behavior of the
>   .ready() method, which is inefficient and can lead to incorrect
>   assumptions about the method's behavior.

TypeScript definition files just don't include deprecated syntax, which still works for the sake of backward compatibility. Your script should look like this:

```
$(() => {
    console.log("Hello World!");
});
```