# Cannot use `$(document).ready` in TypeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript

Using `$(document)` in TypeScript gives the error `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

[image: error screen]

I'm using TypeScript 3.1, jQuery 3.3.1 and @types/jQuery 3.3.29.

Is `$(document)` deprecated and I should use something else or is it an error in the type definition file?

EDIT:
The entire body of this TypeScript file is basically "Hello World!".

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    console.log("Hello World!");
});
```

Comment: Do you call any function with parameters?

Comment: try: `jQuery(document).ready(()`

Comment: `jQuery(document)` gives the same error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$(document).ready(handler)` has two functionally equivalent variants, first is `$().ready(handler)`, and second is direct `$(handler)`.

In jQuery 3.0 first two were deprecated, leaving only `$(handler)`. The official justification is:

> This is because selection has no bearing on the behavior of the `.ready()` method, which is inefficient and can lead to incorrect assumptions about the method's behavior.

TypeScript definition files just don't include deprecated syntax, which still works for the sake of backward compatibility. Your script should look like this:

```
$(() => {
    console.log("Hello World!");
});
```